# How to add a module to workflow configuration list in Liferay 7?

Tags: workflow, liferay-7

When I go to workflow configuration, I only saw default resources in list. So how to add a custom resource (like my custom portlet), that let me configure the asset approval process workflow for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dev.liferay.com is a good source for all kind of Liferay related tutorials.
Have a look at this tutorial on how to make the workflow work for custom assets in Liferay DXP 
https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/liferays-workflow-framework